# Ubuntu 17.10 64bit won't mount Samsung Galaxy A3 any more

Tags: mount, android, 17.10, usb-drive, samsung

The previous Ubuntu versions 16.04, 16.10 and 17.04 (32bit ones) mounted my Samsung Galaxy A3 without problem with USB (2 or 3). I could then access the phone with any file manager, e.g. Files.

After having upgraded to 17.10 64bit, it does not work any more, on 2 completely diffent hardwares with Ubuntu on them. The smartphone is recognized and displayed in Files, but the access button does not give me access to the phone.

After having spent a couple of hours googling, i do not know what to do.

Anybody has an idea? Or have the same problem? Txs for any help.

Answer (score 2):

OK, i got it now... There 2 use cases. One is working, the other not.

Case 1) (working)

1. Unlock the phone
2. Plug the USB cable into the phone
3. Click the button "Allow access to the phone data" in the popup window
4. Access the phone data with files

Case 2) (not working)

1. Plug the USB cable into the phone
2. Unlock the phone
3. Click the button "Allow access to phone data" in the popup window
4. You cannot access to the phone data

The problem is the order of the first 2 operations.

Hoping this post helps...